# Replacing the deprecated stb.subtotal() from sidetable by pd.concat()

Tags: pandas

Bonjour,
How to Replace the deprecated stb.subtotal() from sidetable by pd.concat()

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

import sidetable
df.groupby(['class', 'embark_town', 'sex']).agg({'fare': 'sum'}).stb.subtotal()
```

That produces many lines like this:

```
anaconda3\envs\my_environ\lib\site-packages\sidetable\sidetable.py:445: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  output.append(section.append(subtotal))
```

How to cleanly replace the deprecated stb.subtotal() function of sidetable with pd.concat()?
I don"t see....
I tried:

```
df.groupby(['class', 'embark_town', 'sex']).agg({'fare': 'sum'}).pd.concat()
```

But that produces:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pd'
```

Do you have an idea?
Regards,
Atapalou

Comment: you attempted change makes no sense. The `stb` method is provided by `sidetable`, to fix the issue one needs to alter the code of sidetable. One thing to do in such case is to report the error and [**someone already did!**](https://github.com/chris1610/sidetable/issues/26) Now you just have to wait and update (or use the dev version).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the "bug" has been fixed

Comment: I am not the one proposing this replacement but it is in the alarm message. For whoever wrote it, it must have made sense.

Comment: Yes, this is a warning for a future change in `pandas` API ;)

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Pandas **append** method appears to have been removed since pandas 2.0.0. I rolled back to pandas 1.5.3 and *sidetable* works just fine.

Key issue is when **sidetable** will be revised to switch from *append* to *concat*.